# C++ std::unordered_set SIGFPE exception

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-set, sigfpe

I wrote a program and I'm quite amused by the fact that I'd run it dozens of times -- I've even wrote down results from multiple executions --, and now it does not work.

You might think I'm high as a kite to say so, or that I might have simply changed some lines, but I really **do not recall doing any** alterations whatsoever on the program.

The problem is a `SIGFPE`, that raises up in different executions of the program, according to the input. Happens though the signal is raised while **inserting a value in an `std::unordered_set<Point<T> *>`**.

Here is a snippet of the code where I do such insertion:

```
std::vector<Point<T> *> _point, _centroid;
std::vector<std::unordered_set<Point<T> *> > _cluster;

// Main procedure -- pseudocode
for (point in _point) {
    cluster_id = centroid_with_min_distance(point, _centroid);
    has_changed = _change_cluster(point, cluster_id);
}

// Changes from one "point->_cluster's unordered_set" to "c's unordered_set"
bool _change_cluster(Point<T> *point, const unsigned int& c) {

    if ((point->_cluster == c) &&
        (_cluster[c].find(point) != _cluster[c].end())) {
        return false;
    }

    _cluster[point->_cluster].erase(point);
    _cluster[c].insert(point); // Insertion that raises the SIGFPE exception
    point->_cluster = c;
    return true;

}
```

Here is a considered-important section of valgrind's output:

```
==17636== Invalid read of size 8
==17636==    at 0x40A758: std::pair<std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<
                Point<unsigned int>*, true, false>, bool>
                std::_Hashtable<Point<unsigned int>*, Point<unsigned int>*,
                std::allocator<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                std::_Identity<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                std::equal_to<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                std::hash<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
                std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
                std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, true, true>::
                    _M_insert<Point<unsigned int>* const&>(
                        Point<unsigned int>* const&&&,
                        std::integral_constant<bool, true>) (hashtable.h:966)
==17636==    by 0x408EDA: std::_Hashtable<Point<unsigned int>*,
                 Point<unsigned int>*, std::allocator<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::_Identity<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::equal_to<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::hash<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
                 std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
                 std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, true, true>::
                     insert(Point<unsigned int>* const&) (hashtable.h:400)
==17636==  ... (calls from my program) ...
==17636==  Address 0x620a028 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==17636== 
==17636== 
==17636== Process terminating with default action of signal 8 (SIGFPE)
==17636==  Integer divide by zero at address 0x402D07D7C
==17636==    at 0x40252F: std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing::operator()(
                 unsigned long, unsigned long) const (hashtable_policy.h:376)
==17636==    by 0x40A66C: std::__detail::_Hash_code_base<Point<unsigned int>*,
                 Point<unsigned int>*, std::_Identity<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::equal_to<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::hash<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
                 std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, false>::_M_bucket_index(
                     Point<unsigned int>* const&, unsigned long,
                     unsigned long) const (hashtable_policy.h:758)
==17636==    by 0x40A772: std::pair<std::__detail::_Hashtable_iterator<
                 Point<unsigned int>*, true, false>, bool>
                 std::_Hashtable<Point<unsigned int>*, Point<unsigned int>*,
                 std::allocator<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::_Identity<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::equal_to<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::hash<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
                 std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
                 std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, true, true>::
                     _M_insert<Point<unsigned int>* const&>(
                     Point<unsigned int>* const&&&,
                     std::integral_constant<bool, true>) (hashtable.h:966)
==17636==    by 0x408EDA: std::_Hashtable<Point<unsigned int>*,
                 Point<unsigned int>*, std::allocator<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::_Identity<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::equal_to<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::hash<Point<unsigned int>*>,
                 std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing,
                 std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash,
                 std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, false, true, true>::
                     insert(Point<unsigned int>* const&) (hashtable.h:400)
==17636==    ... (calls from my program) ...
```

The question here is: as I have calculations in my program that may result in divisions by zero -- they are not directly related to this process, though --, is it possible that the **bug** is being shadowed by the insertion? Or should I do some extra treatment while inserting pointers in an `std::unordered_set<T>`?

I'm compiling the program under `x86_64 GNU/Linux`, and I'm using `g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3`.

Comment: Can you post a segment of your code around the function that is failing?  What other operations on the set are you performing?  Also, it APPEARS that you're using `std::hash<Point<T>*>` and `std::equal_to<Point<T>*>` as your hash and equals functions, which means it's hashing based on the address of the object, and not the data in the point itself.

Comment: @DaveS Thanks for the reply. Yes, I'm really storing pointers in the `std::unordered_set<>`, and that's all I want to do, as I need simply to keep track of the objects, with constant time search. I'll add the snippet involved here.

Comment: @Rubens: If your program has undefined behavior, it could run fine for centuries and then crash at the ten billion-th execution. When you work with pointers, it's quite easy to get UB. Another reason could be, that you've been altering the values in the `unordered_set<>`. I believe you need to show us the code if we are expected to provide some help.

Comment: @AndyProwl Thanks, I've tried to narrow down the code to get it straight to the point. Please, check the update!

Comment: @Rubens: I see no `unordered_set<>` here though, just an `unordered_map<>` used as an `unordered_set<>`. Is it a typo?

Comment: @AndyProwl Sorry, that one was a typo ^^

Comment: @Rubens: how do you check that `c` is less than the size of `_cluster`? I see a potential out-of-bounds here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that 'c' is out of the range of `_cluster`.  Can you replace all of the `_cluster[c]` with `_cluster.at(c)`, and see if it finds an out of range error.

The valgrind output indicates that it's an invalid read followed by an integer modulus error.  Since it's doing `hash_code % bucket_count`, I suspect that you accessed out of the range of the vector.

As an aside, naming things that start with `_` can be risky, as if it's in the global namespace, it is technically reserved for the implementation.

Comment: Thanks. I like to name `private members` with an initial `_`, as I don't usually use `this->` -- those instances were in a bigger class, and they were private. I'm trying this solution right now!

Comment: Yep, that's exactly the problem. Geez, I'm so ashamed I didn't get this one -- guess I've been somehow misled by the `SIGFPE` (: Thank you all for the support!